# Making 2 Separate App Delegates For Universal App?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

Should I make 2 separate app delegates for a universal app?  One myAppDelegate, then myAppDelegate_iPhone and myAppDelegate_iPad which are subclasses?  Reason being iPhone should have IBOutlet of NavController while iPad should be UISplitViewController.

Also, how do I separate actions between iPhone and iPad.  For example, a button on iphone may push a view, but on iPad i want to have a small window popup instead rather than a full-screen push.  Do I just use a if/else statement to check if iPad (by uiswitchviewcontroller), then go from there?

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"UISplitViewController") != nil && UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        //currentDeviceType = iPad;
    }
    else {
        //currentDeviceType = iPhone;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems to be along similar lines.

[Universal iPhone/iPad AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844296/universal-iphone-ipad-appdelegate)

This doc from Apple might also prove helpful.

[Introduction to Universal Apps](http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/resources/introductiontouniversalapps.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me quickly how to enable rotation for my viewcontrollers on iPad?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not too familiar with that :P

Answer (score 0):

No need to take two separate application delegates. You can code on the condition...

```
    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){}
```

This will automatically detect the device.

Comment: So I can add UINavigationController and UISplitScreenController to my app delegate in 1 file?

Comment: Yes you can. Just you have to set proper Outlets and maintain application delegate code accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

To enable rotation on the device, you need to return YES to

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```

FOR ALL OF YOUR VIEW CONTROLLERS.

You should also add your supported orientations to your plist or info under xcode 4.

Also keep in mind that stack overflow prefers that a new question be asked when the question topic changes :)