# Creating two targets in XCode 4

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to create two targets for my application iphone and ipad version. 
My question is : Do I need to copy all the files from one target to another , because i found out that there are two AppDelegate files in my project, and what about resource and library files? This is the first time when i am trying to setup a multitarget project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no need to copy source files.  You can click on each file and tell Xcode which target they belong to (The *Target Membership* section of the *File Inspector* tab in the right pane).

Any files that are meant to be different (like the delegate classes you mention) obviously won't be added to both targets.

Comment: so you mean i can safely remove AppDelegate from my second target and
check all files to belong to all targets right?

Comment: @taffarel If the app is *Universal* then that can be achieved with a single app delegate.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3844296/universal-iphone-ipad-appdelegate

Comment: @trojanfoe app is not a Universal, I just want to use same code for two targets and at the and make a two different .app files

Comment: @taffarel OK, so you might be better off keeping them separate, although you can still probably get away with a single app delegate with conditional code for each target.